# activity_home_drawer.xml seems to be empty

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, navigation-drawer

[MY activity_home_drawer.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7kQa.png)

**activity_home_drawer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="@string/menu_home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="@string/menu_gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="@string/menu_slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_tools"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="@string/menu_tools" />
</group>

<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="@string/menu_share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="@string/menu_send" />
    </menu>
</item>

</menu>
```

I was following a tutorial in YouTube about how to create an App Navigation drawer for my android app, while following the procedures, that occurred (see photo above), I'm new to android programming so, can anybody please tell me what's the root cause of this problem and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: You should share more details. You can start by sharing XML code. 
"How do I ask quality questions?" Do research on.

Comment: Apologogizes, I don't know. I'll post it now.

Comment: Have you linked this view to navigationView?

Answer (score 1):

remove this line

```
 tools:showIn="navigation_view"
```

Answer (score 1):

If we look into the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes#toolsshowin), it clearly states that the `tools:showIn` is,

> Intended for: Any root `<View>` in a layout that's referred to by an
>   `<include>`

Basically, `tools:showIn` lets **Android Studio's layout editor** to know where the `View` that uses it should be placed.

From the above explanation we can figure out that `tools:showIn`,

- should be used by a Root `<View>`
- the passing layout should refer this view by an `<include>`

Now, if you look into your source code, you will observe that,

- You are using `tools:showIn` in your menu which is not it is intended for
- You did not `<include>` the `activity_home_drawer.xml` in your `navigation_view` layout. Though you will not be able to do so, as it's not a `<View>`.

For the above mention reason, Android Studio is not able to preview the menu. The workaround to fix this issue is to remove the `tools:showIn` attribute and the tools namespace as well.

### Remove

> ```
> xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
> tools:showIn="navigation_view"
> ```

After refactoring your **activity_home_drawer.xml** menu should look like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="@string/menu_home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="@string/menu_gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="@string/menu_slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_tools"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="@string/menu_tools" />
</group>

<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="@string/menu_share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="@string/menu_send" />
    </menu>
</item>

</menu>
```